# service perl-fcgi start, unrecognized service

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze

From http://supportex.net/2011/11/migrating-otrs-apache-nginx/

I have a file `/usr/local/bin/fastcgi-wrapper.pl` and `/lib/systemd/system/perl-fcgi.service`. *perl-fcgi.service* has following content:

```
[Unit]

Description=otrs-index.pl

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/fastcgi-wrapper.pl
Type=forking
User=otrs
Group=nginx
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After enabling the service with

```
systemctl enable  perl-fcgi.service
```

I run

```
service perl-fcgi start
```

But I get the message

```
perl-fcgi: unrecognized service
```

Why is the service not starting? My server is running on **debian 6.0**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because /etc/init.d/perl-fcgi is missing or without permission +x - http://nginxlibrary.com/perl-fastcgi/